# Getting ERROR while passing send keys in Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to login to https://www.auditanalytics.com/0002/authentication.php to the website using python selenium package . When I pass the email using send keys method I am getting the following ERROR .

```
WebDriverException: Message: target frame detached
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=102.0.1245.44)
```

I just need a solution which I can pass email id and password .

Here is my code

```
exe_path="msedgedriver.exe"
browser=webdriver.Edge(executable path=exe_path)
browser.get("https://www.auditanalytics.com/0002/authentication.php")
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
username=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
username.send_keys("example@org.com")
password=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
password.send_keys("test")
```

Comment: Your elements are not in an iframe.

Comment: Even the other option is not working.

Comment: I have tried without the iframe option and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
browser.get("https://www.auditanalytics.com/0002/authentication.php")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyButtonAccept'))).click()
username=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]')))
username.send_keys("example@org.com")
password=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]')))
password.send_keys("test")
```

Handle the pop up accept all cookies and then proceed to send keys to the element.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```